# Conditionally move mail items according to sender's domain

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to move all received emails that are not from my company's domain (Ex. JohnDeer@tractorworld.com) and does not have my company's name in the subject field to the spam folder.

Here is what I have so far but it gives me a type mismatch error after a couple of hundred iterations:

```
Sub SpamHunter()
    Dim inBox As Folder
    Set inBox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    MsgBox ("Items Found: " & inBox.Items.count)
    Dim mailItem As mailItem
    Dim b As Long
    Dim mailAddress As String
    Dim mailSubject As String
    Dim mailReceived As Date
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 0

    For Each mailItem In inBox.Items

        c = c + 1

        mailAddress = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress
        mailSubject = mailItem.Subject
        mailReceived = mailItem.ReceivedTime

        b = InStr(mailAddress, "mycompany")
        b = b + InStr(mailAddress, "myothercompany")

        If b < 1 Then
            mailItem.Move (Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("_Junk"))
        End If


    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not add a filter rule in outlook? Any way, you could start by looking at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155733%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Comment: You cannot add a filter rule like this I tried. Here is the code I have so far but I get a type mismatch error after a couple of hundred iterations and I can't figure out what is blowing it up:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything in the inbox is a `MailItem`. For example a meeting request is not a `MailItem`.

You need to check that the item is a mailitem before you cast it to that type.

```
Dim o as Object
Dim ixItems as Integer
For ixItems = inBox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
   Set o = inBox.Items.Item(ixItems)
   if TypeName(o) = "MailItem" Then
       Set mailItem = o
       ' loop goes here

        c = c + 1

        mailAddress = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress
        mailSubject = mailItem.Subject
        mailReceived = mailItem.ReceivedTime

        b = InStr(mailAddress, "mycompany")
        b = b + InStr(mailAddress, "myothercompany")

        If b < 1 Then
            mailItem.Move (Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("_Junk"))
        End If

   End If
Next
```

Also, a tip: don't let your variable names clash with type names. I suggest calling your variable `oMailItem` or similar so it is obvious it is a variable not a type.

Comment: AS a side note - do not use "for each" loop when you are modifying the collection - use a "for" loop from Items.Count down to 1 (step -1)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko You are correct, or course. :-)